# Objectify and entity groups

Tags: google-app-engine, persistence, objectify

Here is a question for all the objectify/ app engine gurus out there:

I am creating ojectes with a parent/child relationship by storing the key of the parent object in the child.
This is stored in a object of type Key.   For example let's say I have a car object and tire objects.
The tire objects store the parent key in a variable of type Key.

```
@Entity
Public class Tire{
     @Id Long id;
     Key<Car> ParentKey;

     int size;
}
```

In my app I will need to get all the tires given a certain car.  I can do this with a query:
Tire tires = oft.query(Tire.class).filter("ParentKey",carKey).get();

Is this an approipriate way to accomplish this?  Will this cause any issues with entity groups?  Will this be efficient for a large number of cars and tires?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right now you're not creating a parent/child relationship, at least as is defined by [app engine](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities.html#Entity_Groups_and_Ancestor_Paths). Check out the documentation: adding a parent/child relationship can speed up things because the car and its tyres will be stored physically together, but they can be difficult to remove if at some point they are not longer needed.

To create a parent/child relationship using Objectify, add the `@Parent` annotation:

```
// Use com.googlecode.objectify.Key instead of 
// com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key
@Parent Key<Car> parentKey;
```

Now, in order to get all the tires that belong to a specific car:

```
List<Tyre> tires = ofy().query(Tyre.class).ancestor(carKey).list();
```

Comment: I could see how this would be more efficient.  This method your iterating only through the tires that belong to the car.  What if I need to go through all the tires for all cars?  This creates an entity group issue, right?

Comment: @Patric, are you sure that you need entity grouping there? It mostly used for transactions

Comment: It was my understanding that entity groups are formed whenever there is a transaction, such as creating the tires with the parent relationship.  This puts the car and its tires into an entity.  At least this is my understanding.  I was wondering if it would be possible to query all tires directly when they are stored with the parent relationship.

Comment: This parent/child relationship doesn't put the car ant its tires into the same entity. They will be separate entities, but you will get the benefit of being able of using transactions (as @Patrick pointed out), and the fact that a specific car with its tyres will be stored physically in the same _disk_.

And, there's no problem to query all the tyres. Because they are different entities, you can simply do something like `ofy().query(Tyre.class).list()`.

Comment: OK. Great.  Sounds like Objectify gets rid of some of the issues with querying with JDO and JPA.  Thanks. You get the get the accepted answer!

Answer (score 1):

I'm using exactly same way - no problem.

I don't see there any conflicts with entity groups, and it's working fine for a large groups (at least for a thousands of entities)

P.S. If you need to fetch data that belongs to same group - you don't need to use GAE groups. Even more: entity groups are best for transactions, not for filtering.

Comment: Another issue I thought of is what happens if you update the parent entity?  Doesn't this change the Key for that entity, thus making the key stored in the child invalid?

Comment: If you update parent entity, without changing its ID - Key will not be changed. Key is just an extended wrapper for ID of entity. And, if you know id/name of entity - you can build it by yourself, without problem, like `new Key<Car>(Car.class, 100)`. It will functional as same as already stored key for entity with ID == 100, and can be stored without a problem